# CoreData Handling Sets

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm introducing CoreData to an existing class with objects that include to-Many-Relations.
Before I would have for example something like this:
"Player" is just a normal class with a result array...

```
for (y,result) in player.result!.enumerate() {
```

Now i would  have to do it like this....

```
for (y,result) in (player.relResults!.allObjects as! [CDResult]).enumerate()
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Is there a way to avoid this ugly casting stuff?

Answer (score 0):

An optional to-many relationship is represented in the `NSManagedObject`
subclass as an optional `NSSet`:

```
@NSManaged var results: NSSet?
```

So the type of the target entity of the relationship is lost here,
and *some* casting is needed. But you don't have to convert
the set to an array. You can cast it to a `Set` of the appropriate
type and iterate over the set:

```
for result in player.results! as! Set<CDResult> { ... }
```

Note that `player.results` can be `nil`, so this should be checked
before, or wrapped into an optional binding with `if let` or
`guard let`.

You could also change the property definition to

```
@NSManaged var results: Set<CDResult>?
```

and then simply iterate with

```
for result in player.results! { ... }
```

The disadvantage is that the change is lost if you re-generate the
managed object subclass in Xcode. Perhaps a future version of 
Xcode will create `Set<T>` typed properties for to-many relationships.

(You may also have a look at ["mogenerator"](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) which is an alternative tool
to create the managed object subclasses with some nice additional features. It could be that mogenerator handles this better.)